# Erro ao renderizar PartialView em uma View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, entity-framework-6

Tenho uma *View* e dentro dela quero renderizar uma *PartialView*. O que acontece é que a *partial* é de um *model* diferente, mas que tem relacionamento entre eles.

Quero mostrar uma *partial* como se fosse a `index`, onde eu mostro tudo que está relacionado ao Id passando na `Url` na *action*. Essa *action* que recebe o Id é a *action* de detalhes, pois ela mostra os dados todos. E dentro dessa *action* de detalhes, mostrar essa *partial* que se relaciona com o Id passado.

Eu já havia feito isso antes em um outro projeto. Então resolvi seguir os mesmos passos pra fazer novamente, só que não está dando certo.

Ao renderizar a *View*, um erro já é mostrado:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Web.Mvc.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.AccAvaliacaoComposic_2033E49B3B44E5935B12E9A68FD75A0C5C81F4AB3E35937D92A1C78CB15ACE30', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[MeuProjeto.Models.AccAvaliacaoComposicaoCorporal]'.

E eu não sei mais como fazer pra resolver, pois pelo que vi está tudo certo.

A forma como chamo essa *partial* é: dentro do *controller* `RetRetorno`, tenho uma `actionresult` que se chama `PartialAcc`, que serve para buscar os dados relacionados ao id passado na `url` da *action* de detalhes. Já tentei de tudo, mas não deu certo.

Os códigos que tenho são:

## Action Detalhes

```
 // GET: RetRetorno/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        //RetRetorno retRetorno = db.RetRetorno.Find(id);

        RetRetorno retRetorno = db.RetRetorno.Include(o => o.AccAvaliacaoComposicaoCorporal).
            Include(p => p.CliCliente).AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(f => f.RetId == id);

        if (retRetorno == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        return View(retRetorno);
    }
```

## *Action* que uso pra chamar a *partial*

```
   public ActionResult PartialAcc(int? id)
    {
        //AccAvaliacaoComposicaoCorporal acc = db.AccAvaliacaoComposicaoCorporal.Include(o => o.CliCliente).AsNoTracking().ToList().FirstOrDefault();

        //return View(db.AccAvaliacaoComposicaoCorporal.Include(o => o.CliCliente).AsNoTracking().ToList().FirstOrDefault());

        var acc = db.AccAvaliacaoComposicaoCorporal.AsEnumerable();

        return View(acc);

    }
```

## Na view detalhes

...

```
<h2>Details</h2>

<div>
<h4>RetRetorno</h4>
<hr />

@Html.Partial("PartialAcc", Model.AccAvaliacaoComposicaoCorporal)
```

...

A partial que chamo é como se fosse a index mesmo, mas vou colocar os códigos aqui:

```
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.AccAvaliacaoComposicaoCorporal>

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccPeso)*@
            Peso
        </th>
        <th>
            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(model =>
```

...

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está passando isto:

```
@model MeuProjeto.Models.AccAvaliacaoComposicaoCorporal
```

Sua *Partial* pede isto:

```
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.AccAvaliacaoComposicaoCorporal>
```

Troque `@model` para um objeto simples (não `IEnumerable`) que deve funcionar.

Ficará assim:

```
@model MeuProjeto.Models.AccAvaliacaoComposicaoCorporal

<table class="table table-striped">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AccPeso)
            Peso
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => ...
```

Comment: Mas dessa forma eu poderia mostrar todos os registros? Tipo digamos que eu tenha 10 registros... Sem o IEnumerable, iria mostrar?

Comment: Você pode ou chamar a *Partial* dez vezes (da forma como está) ou chamar a *Partial* uma vez, mas aí a *Partial* terá que ter `@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.AccAvaliacaoComposicaoCorporal>` e aí dentro dela um `@foreach (var item in Model)`. Aí você que decide.

Comment: Então, é dessa forma que estou fazendo... Com o foreach, e esta dando errado.. Não coloquei pelo fato da minha partial ser muito grande... Mas ta dessa forma

Comment: [Dizer que não deu certo não vai resolver coisa alguma](http://www.codingcraft.com.br/2016/06/10/10-frases-idiotas-que-devem-ser-evitadas-na-hora-de-pedir-ajuda-como-pedir-ajuda-apropriadamente/). Se `AccAvaliacaoComposicaoCorporal` faz parte de `RetRetorno`, significa que cada `RetRetorno` tem um, e apenas um objeto do tipo `AccAvaliacaoComposicaoCorporal`. Então dentro do `foreach` que renderiza `RetRetorno` você põe a chamada da *Partial* na forma com que coloquei na resposta: `@model MeuProjeto.Models.AccAvaliacaoComposicaoCorporal`.

Comment: Calma... O que acontece é que um RetRetorno pode ter mais de uma AccAvalicaoComposicaoCorporal... Não um pra um... E sim 1 RetRetorno para muitas AccAvalicaoComposicaoCorporal.

Comment: Então é a segunda forma mesmo, mas você não está passando N elementos. Está passando um só, senão não daria o erro.

Comment: Mesmo com as actions da forma como estão? Na detalhes incluindo e na action pra renderizar a partial retornando uma lista?

Comment: Sim. Tem algo errado na modelagem. Um *debug* resolveria isso bem.

Comment: Eu deguei até o ponto em que tem o @Html.Partial(...). Na action de detalhes tudo é retornado diretinho, só que a action que chama a partial não é chamada..